# ML estimate problem

Tags: complex-analysis, computational-complexity

[image]

I get: $$R\frac{\pi}{e^{-y}}|(z^2+1)|$$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: abs(dz) is R*pi since it's a semi circle, abs (e^zi) is e^-y where y is imaginary part of z, z^2 = (abs(z))^2 = R^2

Comment: Use MathJax. It will make things more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Note the following inequality:

$$|z^2| = |(z^2 + 1) - 1| \leq |z^2 + 1| + 1 \implies |z^2 + 1| \geq |z^2| - 1$$

So we have:

$$
I =\left | \int_C \frac{e^{iz}}{z^2 + 1}dz \right| \leq \int_C \frac{\left | e^{iz} \right |}{\left| z^2 + 1 \right|}|dz| = \int_C \frac{e^{-y}}{\left| z^2 + 1 \right|}|dz|
$$

We are given that $\text{Im}(z) \geq 0$ so $e^{-y} \leq 1$ Using this and the first inequality I derived we get:

$$
I \leq \frac{1}{R^2 - 1} \int_C 1\cdot|dz| = \frac{\pi R}{R^2 - 1}
$$